# What is use of 'return' statement in recursive function that returns nothing

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, recursion

I am using recursive function which fetches some details asynchronously in NodeJS. This function is called recursively for iterating over array of ids.

```
var x = [1, 2, 3];

function rec_fun(index) {
    if (index < x.length) {
        someAsyncFuncCall(x[index], function(response) {
            rec_fun(++index);
        })
    } else {
        // iterated all elements from 'x'
        someAnotherFunctionCall();
    }
}

rec_fun(0); // start iteration

function someAnotherFunctionCall() {
    console.log("finished iteraing data. Can proceed to next flow");
}
```

If huge array is provided as input, then I think, javascript will throw an error `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

`rec_fun` shown in above sample code is not need to return anything. But when it is getting called recursively, is adding 'return' statement is mandatory? Will it affect performance?

Comment: _How 'return' statement is useful in this scenario?_ What return statement do you mean?

Comment: Think the question might have something to do with proper tail calls?

Comment: Why would you make a recursive function to iterate over a huge array? The return statement is not going to help you in any way. The only think it does is exit a function. That can be useful to break a recursion when applicable, but if you just do that at random, it will break the functionality too. :p So the best way to solve this is just iterate smarter, that is, not recursively.

Comment: @B001ᛦ : I have updated a question

Comment: _I have updated a question..._ Still not clear... but look at @GolezTrol comment

Comment: @GolezTrol : I can not use simple `for` loop for iterating because for getting details of element from an array, i need to call an asynchronous function.

Comment: In all function blocks `}` is the same as `return undefined; }`. `return` is used to break end the current function so no more code in that black will be evaluated if `return` happens.

Comment: @Chaitanya Looks like you just want to [await the result of the async call](https://javascript.info/async-await) before moving on to the next item. But also, with async functions, this recursion thing is slightly different, so do you *think* you get that error, or do you actually get it?

Comment: @GolezTrol: Yes. I want to wait till details of current element are fetched. I also can use javascript `foreach` method. But using it I can not stop in between or skip further elements.

Comment: See the link in my previous comment. You actually can `await` (wait for) the result of an async call. That does mean that your function will take a long time to execute (because it will wait for all those calls), and it will have to be made into an async method itself. The tutorial I linked shows how to do all that.

Comment: @GolezTrol: Thanks for the suggestion :) Meanwhile, I also have came across `asyc` library. This library provides 'eachSeries' which seems to be useful as well.

Comment: np. If you get it working before anyone else answers, maybe you can post it as an answer, to help future visitors.